# Simplify Further and find c1 and c2 (Big Theta)

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to find c1 and c2 but having some difficulty proceeding any further.

This is how far I've gotten:

(21n^2 + 97n + 26) (log(1024n^2 + 100)) ∈ θ(n^2 log n)

Not sure how to expand it further and get my c1 and c2.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify just what `c1` and `c2` are. Not everyone defines big theta notation the same way. For example, [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) does not use those constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take c1 and c2 to be 21*2 + epsilon and 21*2 - epsilon for some epsilon > 0 and epsilon < 21*2. Since many values work, choose one. For example, epsilon = 1 satisfies the requirements. So, you could take 43 and 41 as the constant factors.

To prove that these will work you compute the limit of

```
(21n^2 + 97n + 26) (log(1024n^2 + 100)) / (n^2ln(n)) --> 21*2
```

then the definition of limit tells you that there is N, that depends on the epsilon that you chose, such that for all n > N you will have that quotient between 21*2 - epsilon and 21*2 + epsilon. Therefore,

(21*2 - epsilon) n^2ln(n) <= (21n^2 + 97n + 26) (log(1024n^2 + 100)) <= (21*2 + epsilon)n^2ln(n)

for all n > N.

---

What people do is not such much expanding further, but removing terms that won't matter as in

```
21n^2ln(1024n^2)
```

and further

```
21*2n^2ln(n)
```

Note how the 1024 gets removed on the basis that ln(1024n^2)=2ln(n)+ln(1024).

This whole reduction is no a formal proof, only an heuristic to get a candidate, 21*2n^2ln(n), that then gets verified to work by computing the limit above.

---

Note also the column about **Limit Definition** in the table in the [link that you were given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations). The value of those limits (or limsups) tells you which constants to use in the formal definition.

---

Review on limits:

Remember that the [definition of limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition)

```
lim F(n) = a
```

is that for all epsilon > 0 there is N such that for all n > N you will have

```
a - epsilon <= F(n) <= a + epsilon
```

If F(n) is a fraction f(n)/g(n) like our fraction above, then this inequality implies

```
(a - epsilon)g(n) <= f(n) <= (a + epsilon)g(n)
```

This is how the definition of limits relates to the constants in the inequalities.

Comment: @LifeOfJona Let me know which part.